# comparing itemgetter objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I noticed that `operator.itemgetter` objects don't define `__eq__`, and so their comparison defaults to checking identity (`is`).

Is there any disadvantage to defining two `itemgetter` instances as equal whenever their initialization argument lists compare as equal?

Here's one use case of such a comparison. Suppose you define a sorted data structure whose constructor requires a key function to define the sort. Suppose you want to check if two such data structures have identical key functions (e.g., in an `assert` statement; or to verify that they can be safely merged; etc.).

It would be nice if we could answer that question in the affirmative when the two key functions are `itemgetter('id')`. But currently, `itemgetter('id') == itemgetter('id')` would evaluate to `False`.

Comment: I don't see how this would be helpful... That said, seeing that `itemgetter` is defined in C, you could hack a class together that overrides `__getitem__` and then run the two getters on it to check if the same item was accessed. This is not an elegant or fast solution, but I don't see how you could do a lot better.

Comment: @NiklasB. I updated the question to provide a motivation for this.

Comment: I would use `lambda` expression in this case.

Comment: @NiklasB. I don't think so, many built-in functions in Python accept key as a function, it's easier to understand if new `key` parameter is also a function.

Comment: @Satoru: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @NiklasB. For example, check `blist.sorteddict` or `blist.sortedset`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Niklas's answer is quite clever, but needs a stronger condition as `itemgetter` can take multiple arguments

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import count

def cmp_getters(ig1, ig2):
   if any(not isinstance(x, itemgetter) for x in (ig1, ig2)):
      return False
   d1 = defaultdict(count().next)
   d2 = defaultdict(count().next)
   ig1(d1)                                 # populate d1 as a sideeffect
   ig2(d2)                                 # populate d2 as a sideeffect
   return d1==d2
```

Some testcases

```
>>> cmp_getters(itemgetter('foo'), itemgetter('bar'))
False
>>> cmp_getters(itemgetter('foo'), itemgetter('bar','foo'))
False
>>> cmp_getters(itemgetter('foo','bar'), itemgetter('bar','foo'))
False
>>> cmp_getters(itemgetter('bar','foo'), itemgetter('bar','foo'))
True
```

Comment: That would work perfectly, but I was actually wondering if `class itemgetter` should implement this functionality (which would obviously be a lot easier, since it can rely on the internal state of the instance).

Comment: @max, well the itemgetter class is implemented in C, so you can't really add that functionality to it, You could propose a pep though

Comment: FYI PEPs are not needed for such small things.

Comment: +1, really clever to check the order order in which the getters are applied by using `count`. I didn't even know that `itemgetter` could take multiple arguments! And @max: I already mentioned the fact that this cannot be solved elegantly in my first comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`itemgetter` returns a callable. I hope you **do not want to compare callables**. Correct? Because the returned callable's id are not gauranteed to be same even if you pass the same arguments.

```
def fun(a):
    def bar(b):
        return a*b
    return bar

a = fun(10)
print id(a(10))

a = fun(10)
print id(a(10))
```

On the other hand, when you use the itemgetter callable as an accessor to access the underlying object, then that object's comparison would be used to perform the comparison
It is illustrated in the [Sorting Howto using the operating module functions](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Operator_Module_Functions).

Comment: I didn't mean to compare *any* callable, I meant to compare only `itemgetter` instances (which are indeed callables)! Due to the semantics of `itemgetter`, they seem to be safe to compare based on the initialization arguments. Am I missing anything?